# How can I improve the code quality of this game class

Tags: javascript

I am making an incremental-memory-game similar to this https://www.crazygames.com/game/incremental-memory

I am not very satisfied of how spaghetti this code is.
I am trying to learn to improve my code quality, and make it as professional as it should, I  hope if you an try to restructure this code to make it very inovative and clear to read.

This is a code snippet:

```
export default class Board {
  #hearts;
  constructor(hearts) {
  ...
 addClickEventHandlers() {
    let trueCount = 0;
    let clickCount = 0;

    const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");

    gridItems.forEach((button, index) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        clickCount++;

        if (clickCount <= 3) {
          if (this.#cells[index]) {
            this.setTile(button, true);
            trueCount++;
          } else this.setTile(button, false);
        } else return;

        if (trueCount === 3) {
          // Display the win message
          console.log("You win!");
        } else if (clickCount === 3 && trueCount < 3) {
          this.#hearts--;
          this.setHearts();
        }
      });
    });
  }
setHearts() {
    const heartsContainer = document.querySelector(".hearts");

    while (heartsContainer.firstChild) {
      heartsContainer.removeChild(heartsContainer.firstChild);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.#hearts; i++) {
      // Create a new SVG element
      let svgElement = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "svg"
      );

      // Set the attributes of the SVG element
      svgElement.setAttribute("class", "heartSvg");
      svgElement.setAttribute("width", "32");
      svgElement.setAttribute("clip-rule", "evenodd");
      svgElement.setAttribute("fill", "#fff4f4");
      svgElement.setAttribute("fill-rule", "evenodd");
      svgElement.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");
      svgElement.setAttribute("stroke-miterlimit", "2");
      svgElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
      svgElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

      // Create the path element
      let pathElement = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "path"
      );

      // Set the attributes of the path element
      pathElement.setAttribute(
        "d",
        "m12 5.72c-2.624-4.517-10-3.198-10 2.461 0 3.725 4.345 7.727 9.303 12.54.194.189.446.283.697.283s.503-.094.697-.283c4.977-4.831 9.303-8.814 9.303-12.54 0-5.678-7.396-6.944-10-2.461z"
      );
      pathElement.setAttribute("fill-rule", "nonzero");

      // Append the path element to the SVG element
      svgElement.appendChild(pathElement);

      // Append the SVG element to the hearts container
      heartsContainer.appendChild(svgElement);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions about improving working code should be asked on [Code Review Stack Exchange](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil: Being on-topic elsewhere is __not__ a reason to close this (or any) question.  There are good reasons to close this one, but that isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use constants for fixed or repeated values in your code. For example, use a constant for the tiles per row, the hearts, the SVG attributes, etc. This makes your code easier to change and update.

Use helper functions to avoid repeating code or logic. For example, use a helper function to make and add an SVG element with a path, instead of writing the same code many times in setHearts. Use a helper function to check if the user won or lost, instead of writing the same logic in addClickEventHandlers.

Use comments to explain your code. For example, use comments to say what each function does, what each variable holds, what each condition checks, etc. This makes your code easier to read and fix.

```
// A constant for the number of tiles per row
const TILES_PER_ROW = 3;

// A constant for the number of hearts
const HEARTS = 3;

// A constant for the SVG attributes
const SVG_ATTRIBUTES = {
  class: "heartSvg",
  width: "32",
  clipRule: "evenodd",
  fill: "#fff4f4",
  fillRule: "evenodd",
  strokeLinejoin: "round",
  strokeMiterlimit: "2",
  viewBox: "0 0 24 24",
  xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
};

// A constant for the heart path
const HEART_PATH =
  "m12 5.72c-2.624-4.517-10-3.198-10 2.461 0 3.725 4.345 7.727 9.303 12.54.194.189.446.283.697.283s.503-.094.697-.283c4.977-4.831 9.303-8.814 9.303-12.54 0-5.678-7.396-6.944-10-2.461z";

export default class Board {
  #hearts;
  constructor(hearts) {
    // ...
  }

  // A function that adds click event handlers to each tile
  addClickEventHandlers() {
    // A variable that stores the number of correct tiles clicked
    let correctTiles = 0;

    // A variable that stores the number of tiles clicked
    let clickedTiles = 0;

    // Get all the grid items
    const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");

    // Loop through each grid item
    gridItems.forEach((button, index) => {
      // Add a click event listener to each button
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Increment the clicked tiles count
        clickedTiles++;

        // If the clicked tiles count is less than or equal to the tiles per row
        if (clickedTiles <= TILES_PER_ROW) {
          // If the current cell is correct
          if (this.#cells[index]) {
            // Reveal the tile as correct
            this.revealTile(button, true);

            // Increment the correct tiles count
            correctTiles++;
          } else {
            // Reveal the tile as incorrect
            this.revealTile(button, false);
          }
        } else return;

        // Check if the user has won or lost the game
        this.checkGameStatus(correctTiles, clickedTiles);
      });
    });
  }

  // A function that reveals a tile as correct or incorrect
  revealTile(button, isCorrect) {
    // If the tile is correct
    if (isCorrect) {
      // Set the background color to green
      button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      // Set the background color to red
      button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }

  // A function that checks if the user has won or lost the game
  checkGameStatus(correctTiles, clickedTiles) {
    // If the correct tiles count is equal to the tiles per row
    if (correctTiles === TILES_PER_ROW) {
      // Display the win message
      console.log("You win!");
    } else if (clickedTiles === TILES_PER_ROW && correctTiles < TILES_PER_ROW) {
      // Decrement the hearts count
      this.#hearts--;

      // Update the hearts display
      this.setHearts();
    }
  }

  // A function that updates the hearts display
  setHearts() {
    // Get the hearts container
    const heartsContainer = document.querySelector(".hearts");

    // Remove all the existing children of the hearts container
    while (heartsContainer.firstChild) {
      heartsContainer.removeChild(heartsContainer.firstChild);
    }

    // Loop through the number of hearts
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#hearts; i++) {
      // Create and append an SVG element with the heart path
      this.createAndAppendSvg(heartsContainer, HEART_PATH);
    }
  }

  // A helper function that creates and appends an SVG element with a given path
  createAndAppendSvg(container, path) {
    // Create a new SVG element
    let svgElement = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "svg"
    );

    // Set the attributes of the SVG element from the constant
    for (let key in SVG_ATTRIBUTES) {
      svgElement.setAttribute(key, SVG_ATTRIBUTES[key]);
    }

    // Create the path element
    let pathElement = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "path"
    );

    // Set the attributes of the path element
    pathElement.setAttribute("d", path);
    pathElement.setAttribute("fill-rule", "nonzero");

    // Append the path element to the SVG element
    svgElement.appendChild(pathElement);

    // Append the SVG element to the container
    container.appendChild(svgElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: I genuinely appreciate the time you've taken to improve my code.